# How to add multiple columns to x axis?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am new to R language, and i'm trying to learn how to create a visualization for the data frame of my students degrees.
My table is somewhat like this, but bigger:

| names | grade_one | grade_two | grade_three | grade_four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ana | 5.7 | 6.3 | 4.0 | 5.0 |
| Beth | 3.5 | 5.0 | 7.0 | 8.0 |
| Rick | 9.0 | 9.0 | 9.0 | 9.0 |
| Zoe | 8.0 | 8.7 | 8.0 | 9.0 |

etc

I want to put 'names' on y axis, and the grades 'one','two','three' and so on x axis, and thought about making a line visualization showing the evolution of the students. I would appreciate too if i can give random colors to each name of my 12 students of this classroom to improve viz.

I tried this one and other attempts without success:

`ggplot(data=notas)+geom_line(mapping=aes(x=grade_one+grade_two,y=names))`

I can do this on sheets but would be great learning how to make on RStudio

Would appreciate any help!

Edit:

I already saw the topic "how-to-create-a-ggplot-bar-chart-with-multiple-columns-of-data-for-y"

Maybe because i'm new to R, idk, i think its slightly different. I want to make a line chart, which each student has its own line on the chart, going from left to right, giving them random colors. I see now that values should be on y axis, the four grades on x axis; and each line showing their performance are labelled on the right side of the chart. But if it's a similar code as the other topic, *idk how to adapt*.

The ideia behind the line chart in this case, its to compare the evolution of the students between themselves, like "oh, look how at this point the student A exceeded the student B". The bars chart would reproduce more a isolated view of each one, which its not what i seek. Lines crossing each other would be ideal.

Also its not a school homework. I'm the teacher and i'm want to teach them graphical analysis and of course i'm practicing R too.

Comment: If this is a school assignment / homework, please read [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and edit your post accordingly. If it isn't homework, I suggest you investigate the `pivot_longer()` function from the [tidyr package](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) then plot the 'pivoted' data with `ggplot(aes(x = grade, y = value, color = names, group = names)) + geom_line()` and go from there

Comment: fyi `coord_flip` largely unnecessary since Mar 2020's ggplot2 3.3.0: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#bi-directional-geoms-and-stats

Comment: Agree that reshaping to long format is first step. Then barplot with student and year as x categories, then coord_flip to make the bars horizontal.